# Windows 8 Dell Computer Disk errors

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I own a "Dell XPS 8700 Desktop | Intel Core i7 | 1GB Graphics" Windows 8 (upgraded to 8.1); I bought it on December 1st, 2013. Recently, it stopped working...

Almost ever since I got the computer, it would randomly freeze up, though only ever so often. Normally it would be when my monitor was sleeping. Then, all I could do was hold down the start button until it shut off... and then turn it back on again. So about a week ago, it froze up again, so I turned it off. I then turned it on and went away to do something else. When I came back it was frozen AGAIN, so I turned it back off and on, but this time, something was wrong. On my usual Dell loading screen, the computer told me `Repairing disk errors. This might take more than an hour to complete.` Or something like that. It also gave me an error code which I stupidly forgot to write down. The process took about 3 hours and in the end it told me the repair had failed...

So, I turned it off and on again. This time, the dell loading screen said `Diagnosing your PC` and then `Attempting repairs`. After that it came up with a screen that said:

```
Automatic Repair 
Automatic Repair coudldn't repair your PC 
Press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC or "Shut down" to turn off your PC.
Log file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt
```

Pressing Advanced options brings up a screen that has options such as "Use a device", "Refresh your PC", "Reset your PC", "System Restore", "System Image Recovery", and "Startup Repair".
I've tried all the options excluding the "Reset your PC" and none of them worked. "System Restore" and "System Image Recovery" both said something like "No restore points have been created on your computer's system drive" and "Windows cannot find a system image on this computer".

After playing in the Advanced Options for a little bit, I selected the "Startup Settings" option which Restarted the PC and allowed me to use the F12 key. I then went to the Diagnostics and ran the thorough test mode: everything was in working order...

Going back to the Advanced options screen, I selected the "Command Prompt" option. It started on X: drive. Going to the C: drive, I used the dir command. Will this show me all my computer files (Diagnostics *said* Hard Drive was working)? Because it only showed me the lack thereof.

```
27 File(s)     3,952,157 bytes
15 Dir(s)  797,842,903,040 bytes free
```

C:\Program Files and Program Files (x86) are both empty...
C:\Windows only contains \Logs\PBR\ and a few documents none of which seemed important...

So, was my Hard drive cleared or something? Or does this command prompt not show all of my data? :O

#### Installed software

One of the reasons I couldn't bring myself to try out the "Reset your PC" option, was because I've installed a bit of software, a lot of which I don't use, but some of which I don't want to have to remember and install again. My software included things such as:
Gimp, Paint.NET, Blender, Finale, Reaper, Audacity... Mostly software in those categories.

More recently, I'd just purchased [EastWest Quantum Leap Symphonic Orchestra (Gold Edition)](http://soundsonline.com/Symphonic-Orchestra). The installation of 33 GB took most of an afternoon... This was maybe a week or a little more before my computer stopped working.

Then, probably *the most* recently installed--if installation it can be called--was [mineshafter](http://mineshafter.info)... Basically all it did was download "Mineshafter_Launcher.jar". Seemed legit... and worked too. This might have been the day before it happened. I don't think I downloaded or installed anything on the day of the shutdown.

---

Besides the software, I had a number of project files, mostly from Visual Studio and Reaper, which I would rather not lose. Or have I already lost them? Should I just get over it and try the Reset PC option? Who knows, maybe that doesn't work either.

---

<sub>P.S. I do have a disk that says "Dell XPS 8700 Drivers and Utilities, Use this disc only to reinstall the software already installed on your computer. Contents: Device drivers, Utilities". I don't seem to have anything else that came with the PC.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like you suffered data loss due to a HDD failure.  At this point there isn't much you can do.  I can almost guarantee you that unless you generated a new image, the `Refresh` and `Reset` options, will NOT work.  If I am right Dell will have to send you media to install Windows 8 from scratch.

Comment: It shouldn't be freezing at all. As it's an OEM PC presumably you could have got Dell to fix it before it may or may not have caused problems. However, I've made worse mistakes. If it's still in it's warranty period you can probably still ask for them to attempt to fix it. Or you can take the quick option - manually install a new HDD and either get Dell to send you a windows install disk as mentioned above or buy one. I don't know how good Dell customer support is so I can't comment on that.

Comment: I think your best option for data recovery is to put the HDD in an external cage and salvage what you can with another computer.